# Tengo problemas para subir un archivo con php

Tags: php, mysql

Pongo el codigo en el netbeans y no me carga el documento .jpg que le pido que se pase a la carpeta uploads. adjunto el codigo php. me he guiado con algunos ejemplos y he hecho varias maneras de hacerlo pero no funciona, no traslada la imagen a la carpeta deseada
PD: el name del input del fichero es "fichero"

````
    ```
<?php
$formatos = array('.jpg', '.pdf');
$directorio='uploads/';
$subirArchivo=$directorio.basename($_FILES['fichero']['name']);
if (isset($_POST['insertar'])) {
    $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
    $descripcion = $_POST["descripcion"];
    $proceso = $_POST["proceso"];
    $fichero = $_POST["fichero"];
    $id;

    $insertardatos = "INSERT INTO ficheros VALUES('$nombre','$descripcion','$proceso','$fichero','$id')";
    $ejecutarInsertar = mysqli_query($enlace, $insertardatos);
    if (!$ejecutarInsertar) {
        echo "Error en la linea de SQL";
    } else {
        $ext = substr($nombre, strrpos($nombreArchivo, '.'));
        if (in_array($ext, $formatos)) {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fichero']['tmp_name'], $subirArchivo)) {
                echo "Archivo subido";
            } else {
                echo "archivo error";
            }
        } else {
            echo "error archivo";
        }
    }
}
//insertar el archivo
//eliminar el archivo
?>
```
````

Comment: si se ingresan los datos en la base de dato pero no se traslada el documento

Comment: ¿Recibes algún error de la función move_uploaded_file ?, de todas formas, ¿Has comprobado que el usuario que esta ejecutando el código PHP(normalmente www si es el servidor) tiene permiso de escritura sobre la carpeta uploads?

Answer (score 1):

La subida de un archivo en php es algo trivial. Estas son las cosas que debes tomar en cuenta:

1. El formulario html debe ser enviado usando el método post y debe tener el atributo enctype="multipart/form-data"
2. Debes tener permisos de escritura en el directorio destino. Es decir, donde la función move_uploaded_file va a poner el archivo subido
3. Debes tener bien presente que aunque el formulario se envíe usando post, el archivo llegará en la matriz $_FILES, no $_POST

Lo demás son detalles relacionados con la configuración de php (php.ini) y rara vez el problema está ahí. Estas son las configuraciones que tendrías que revisar:

- memory_limit
- max_execution_time
- post_max_size
- max_file_uploads
- upload_max_filesize
- file_uploads
- upload_tmp_dir
- max_input_time

Una vez haces submit de tu archivo, lo primero que debes evaluar en el script es si hubo algún error, esto lo haces con:

```
<?php

if (!$_FILES['fichero']['error']) { // no error?
    // todo está bien, hagamos maravillas!
}
```

Eso es todo.
He modificado tu código con algunas recomendaciones en comentarios, espero e sirva:

```
<?php

// mientras desarrollas deberías habilitar el muestreo de errores
// aquí he puesto una forma pero lo ideal es que tu servidor este
// configurado para el ambiente de desarrollo
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$directorio = __DIR__ . '/uploads';

if (isset($_POST['insertar']) && isset($_FILES['fichero'])) {
    if (!$_FILES['fichero']['error']) {
        $nombre      = isset($_POST["nombre"]) ? trim($_POST['nombre']) : '';
        $descripcion = isset($_POST["descripcion"]) ? trim($_POST['descripcion']) : '';
        $proceso     = isset($_POST["proceso"]) ? trim($_POST['proceso']) : '';
        // fichero viene en $_FILES, no en $_POST
        $fichero = $_FILES["fichero"]['name'];
        // he eliminado la variable $id porque no esta inicializada
        
        // en este punto, es conveniente agregar una validación sobre los datos que irán en la query
        // porque si no, podríamos estar enviando datos inválidos a mysql
        // para el ejemplo asumiremos que la descripción es opcional
        if (!$nombre || !$proceso) {
            exit('error: el nombre y el proceso son requeridos');
        }
        
        // aquí validamos que el archivo sea del tipo esperado
        // pero esto no debes hacerlo con el nombre del archivo
        // sino con el mime type que viene en el índice type
        $extension = null;
        
        if (
            strpos($_FILES['fichero']['type'], 'jpg') !== false
            || strpos($_FILES['fichero']['type'], 'jpeg') !== false
        ) {
            $extension = 'jpg';
        }
        
        if (strpos($_FILES['fichero']['type'], 'pdf') !== false) {
            $extension = 'jpg';
        }
        
        if ($extension === null) {
            exit('error: el tipo de archivo no es válido');
        }
        
        // después de las validaciones el código no debe fallar
        // somos libres de hacer el insert y mover los archivos
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fichero']['tmp_name'], $directorio . '/' . $fichero);
        
        // aquí es importante que los valores de la query sean escapados
        // para evitar ataques de inyección de sql. Esto lo logras con la
        // función mysqli_escape_string. Este paso no es opcional. Alguien
        // podría robar y/o destruir tus datos si no lo haces
        $nombre      = mysqli_escape_string($enlace, $nombre);
        $descripcion = mysqli_escape_string($enlace, $descripcion);
        $proceso     = mysqli_escape_string($enlace, $proceso);
        $fichero     = mysqli_escape_string($enlace, $fichero);
        
        // siempre es bueno aplicar formatos a las consultas
        $sql    = "
            INSERT INTO ficheros 
            VALUES('$nombre','$descripcion','$proceso','$fichero', '')
        ";
        
        // raro, pero todo puede pasar
        if (!mysqli_query($enlace, $sql)) {
            exit('error en la query: '. mysqli_errno($enlace));
        }
        
        exit('Registro exitoso. id#' . mysqli_insert_id($enlace));
    }
}
```

buena suerte!